# Mathematics Book Recommendation

Tags: book-recommendation

I am looking for a book that is regarded as the 'classics' of the field.

For example,

- Algebraic Number theory - Cassels Frohlich
- Complex analysis - Ahlfors
- Category Theory - MacLane
- Topology - Munkres

What are the classical books of other fields such as fourier analysis, set theory, or differential equation?

I am making a comprehensive list of mathematical classics, so the book of any field is welcomed.

Comment: Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*

Comment: FYI, an earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055713/what-are-some-classic-books-in-mathematics) that was similar was closed as  opinion-based. It's also a very broad question that's not amenable to a single best answer, so at minimum (if it remains open) it should probably be a community wiki. That said, for Fourier analysis, certainly Zygmund's *Trigonometric Series* would qualify, as would anything by Elias Stein on the topic.

Comment: These are not necessarily my favorite books, they are just some books that I think are considered to be classics. Real analysis: baby Rudin; measure theory: Royden, also Rudin; Linear Algebra: Hoffman and Kunze; Differential Topology: Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint by Milnor; Algebra: Herstein, Artin, Lang; Number Theory: Hardy and Wright; Smooth manifolds: Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak, Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres; Differential Geometry: A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry by Spivak; Functional analysis: Kreyszig, Rudin; History of Math: Stillwell